# Is there option to convert mongoDB cursor to array quickly with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have got a problem with converting MongoDb cursor to array using PHP. I have 40 000 rows and it takes about 40 seconds to convert it but only 19 miliseconds to get it from mongo. Is there any option to make it faster?

I tried Cursor->getArray and iterator_to_array and it take huge amount of time to complete it. My data in MongoDb has got maximum four nestings, do You think that reducing the nesting could reduce converting time ?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: 40,000 rows? Copying and reifying all that data into a PHP array takes a lot of memory and time. You should refactor your code to not use arrays, but the provided iterator if possible.

Comment: I have just checked what you suggested and it seems that I have to use foreach on the cursor but using only foreach don't give me access to data. If I understood it right at every passing of foreach loop I should run ->toArray or iterator_to_array on it, it is possible to be faster than toArray on whole object?

Comment: Perhaps it would help knowing why you think you need to bring all the data into the program at once. Most libraries dealing with databases use iterators because of your issue, it is infeasible to bring in all the data in a table, as it could grow quite large. And databases are supposed to provide enough functionality in their selects to avoid having to process the *entire* table in the driving program. You *should* be able to refactor your program to process results from the DB one at a time. If you cannot, for whatever reason, your question should be revised asking how to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I want to convert data from mongo to aggregate in Domain Driven Design so i must iterate over whole data which i received from mongo. Do You think that with mongo cursor i can acomplish that faster than with array? At that moment i can't imagine how it wolud be possible to make faster converting row after row rather than take whole array and put it in foreach loop, Could You advise me something in that way, please ? :)

Comment: Well you might think it wouldn't be faster using an iterator, but it is. Think about it this way. To bring it in using an array, you first have to iterate over all the data to make the array, then you have to iterate over the array for whatever purpose you need. This also brings in all the data into memory, consuming a whole lot of memory, which takes a long time to iterate over because of cache effects. If you avoid the intermediate array caching and just process the results from the DB, you will save a lot of time. I'm not familiar with the technology you are using, but that is fundamental.

Comment: OK, but moving the cursor is one problem but there is second one. If I understood it rigth, cursor will iterate over most outside "array", but what if i want to get into object over which it iterates. F.e. mongo returns something like {outer_array1:{inner_array:{}},outer_array2:{inner_array:{}}}, if i have understood it right cursor will iterate over outer_arrays, but what should i do if i want to access inner_array? And what about accessing to pure data, not only pointer to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying and reifying 40,000 rows into a PHP array takes a lot of memory and time. You should refactor your code to not use arrays, but the provided 'cursor' iterator if possible.

The iterator will iterate over each of the documents in a collection that match the query (arguments to `find()`). Each document is brought in similar to the way a json object is (bson, Mongo's storage format, being inspired by json), which is an PHP array.

If you wanted to access an internal array in the document for each document matched.

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
     echo $doc["inner_array"] . "\n";
}
```